# Azure AD attributes synchronization with Zendesk

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml, zendesk, zendesk-app

I'm setting up a SSO functionality through Azure AD and Zendesk with SAML.

The SAML login works fine, but I have to include custom user fields (available in Azure AD) with Zendesk and keep them synchronized.

I have completed a first synchronization attempt and only certain user attributes have been (automatically) synchronized:

- Title
- Department

Those two attributes were not included in Zendesk; although, they've been instantly updated with correct Azure AD attribute values and they've been automatically mapped to the correct Zendesk custom user field (that was automatically created).

The problem is that I have to synchronize other attributes too. I have tried with *attribute mapping* from Azure AD, and I can't select Zendesk's custom user fields that I have created.

How can I make the custom user fields on Zendesk "visible" to Azure AD for the mapping? I think I've visited almost every piece of documentation online, but it doesn't seem to be helpful because no matter what I do, the custom user fields from Zendesk are note visible for attribute mapping in Azure AD

Another great problem is that I do not have direct access to Azure, so troubleshooting is a bit complicated on this side.

- I have tried to add different SAML claims to Azure.
- Imported Custom User Fields in Azure AD for external users, connected it to Zendesk and then added a new claim as an External Expression. But the external attribute selection menu shows no options for Zendesk attributes (that are already created).
- Followed the SAML set-up for Zendesk from the Microsoft docs. SSO works, but synchronization doesn't.